# Что обозначает эта запись?

Tags: c++

Что обозначает такая запись? поставило в тупик, применением "::" несколько раз.

```
typename FGameMenuItem::FOnOptionChanged::TSPMethodDelegate< UserClass >::FMethodPtr InMethod
```

Comment: разделители namespace

Comment: Скорее вложенные типы. typename слева указывает компилятору, что это имя типа.

Comment: `::` используется для разделения пространств имен как namespace так и пространств имен class и struct (в случае если используются вложеные). `:` занято для членов класса, поэтому заложили такой знак.

Comment: Или одно, или другое. `typename` намекает, что это зависимое имя внутри шаблона.

Answer (score 0):

Данный оператор `::` называется *Оператор разрешения области видимости*. В случае наличия вложенных классов `class`/`struct` и/или пространств имён `namespace` с его помощью обеспечивается доступ к нужному имени. Например:

```
namespace N 
{
    struct C 
    {
        struct D 
        {
            static int i;   
        };
    };
}
```

Для доступа из глобального пространства имён к статической переменной `i` нужно написать `N::C::D::i`.

Подробнее об операторе разрешения области видимости есть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b451xz31.aspx).

Наличие же `typename` вначале говорит о том, что зависимое от шаблона имя является типом, а не переменной.